# Ember Acceptance Test Failing in PhantomJS but Passing in Chrome

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, acceptance-testing

I'm trying to write an acceptance test for my Ember app and I seem to be having some trouble when it comes to PhantomJS and the Ember test server.

I'm running the following versions:

```
Ember      : v1.13.6
Ember Data : v1.13.7
```

PhantomJS is failing with the following error:

```
Died on test #1     at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:2934
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:6640
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:31
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:21
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:40
            at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:6647: Can't find variable: DS
```

Is this a known issue?

The test is running fine within the chrome runner.

Here is my ember-cli-build.js (Brocfile):

```
/* global require, module */
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  // Build Options
  var options = {
    // Build for development (ember s)
    development: {
      sassOptions: {
        includePaths: ['bower_components/materialize/sass']
      }
    },

    // Build for deployments
    dev_deploy: {
      sassOptions: {
        includePaths: ['bower_components/materialize/sass']
      },

      fingerprint: {
        enabled: true,
        prepend: 'redacted',
        extensions: ['js', 'css', 'png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'woff', 'ttf']
      }
    },

    // Build for deployments
    staging_deploy: {
      sassOptions: {
        includePaths: ['bower_components/materialize/sass']
      },

      fingerprint: {
        enabled: true,
        prepend: 'redacted',
        extensions: ['js', 'css', 'png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'woff', 'ttf']
      }
    },

    prod_deploy: {
      sassOptions: {
        includePaths: ['bower_components/materialize/sass']
      },

      fingerprint: {
        enabled: true,
        prepend: 'redacted',
        extensions: ['js', 'css', 'png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'woff', 'ttf']
      }
    }
  };

  var env = process.env.EMBER_ENV || 'development';

  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, options[env]);

  // IMPORTED LIBRARIES
  app.import('vendor/js/ember-uploader.named-amd.js', {
    exports: {
      'ember-uploader': [ 'default' ]
    }
  });

  app.import('vendor/js/faye-browser.js');
  app.import('vendor/js/Util.js');
  app.import('vendor/js/CanvasVirtualJoyStick.js');
  app.import('vendor/js/CanvasZoomController.js');
  app.import('vendor/js/chosen.jquery.js');

  app.import('vendor/css/chosen.css');

  return app.toTree();
};
```

Here is my test:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import startApp from 'teal-turtle/tests/helpers/start-app';

var application;

module('Acceptance | platforms', {
  beforeEach: function() {
    application = startApp();
  },

  afterEach: function() {
    Ember.run(application, 'destroy');
  }
});

test('visiting /platforms', function(assert) {
  authenticateSession();
  visit('/platforms');

  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/platforms');
  });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you have a working version recently or is the right out of the box? also -how much code do you have in the app so far (not a lot of detail in your question to help debug why it's broken)

Comment: @ToranBillups With this app I haven't seen a working version yet, starting a bit late in the game when it comes to tests (unfortunately). There's quite a bit in the app. Are there specific areas that would be helpful for you to see?

Comment: what shows up on the line in your stacktrace (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:6647) is it a ember-data model? what is in your Brocfile.js ? any special ember-data hacks? do you have ember-data in your bower.json file and your package.json file?

Comment: @ToranBillups I've added the Brocfile to my question. Line 6647 of test-support.js is a call to `TestLoader.load();`. We don't have any special ember data hacks and it is in the bower.json and package.json files. The app works as expected in the Chrome test runner and when using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed you were using .bind in the route file (platform) and .bind isn't very phantomJS friendly :( so I did the following...

Added the es5 shim and broccoli funnel to your package.json

```
"broccoli-funnel": "^0.2.3",
"es5-shim": "^4.0.5"
```

Next I opened the ember-cli-build.js (prev known as the Brocfile)

```
var funnel = require('broccoli-funnel');
var es5Shim = funnel('node_modules/es5-shim', {
    files: ['es5-shim.js'],
    destDir: '/assets'
});

return app.toTree([es5Shim]);
```

And finally I added the es5 shim to your tests/index.html above vendor.js

```
<script src="assets/es5-shim.js"></script>
```

Below is a full commit on github showing all the files changed (note: Brocfile in this commit example because I'm using an older ember-cli version)

https://github.com/toranb/ember-cli-simple-store/commit/4f46a392b3be0ec93864342ba2edddbd3430e293

Comment: Ah, nice! I really appreciate your work here :)
I had a feeling it was something messing with PhantomJS since the chrome build worked fine.
The error message I got really threw me off.

Comment: you aren't alone - the error wasn't helpful at all but when I saw our good old friend "bind" I knew a place we could start

Comment: This is great. We had a similar issue which wasn't a problem on PhantomJS 2.0 but it was on the build server which runs PhantomJS 1.9.7. Putting the es5-shim in place fixed it!

Comment: Legend! @ToranBillups, the exact answer I was banging my head looking for.