# Scraping React Site with Phantomjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am scraping a website that is using React components, using PhantomJS in Nodejs.

With this: https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node

Here is the code:

```
phantom.create().then(ph => {
    _ph = ph;
    return _ph.createPage();
}).then(page => {
    _page = page;
    return _page.open(url);
}).then(status => {
    return _page.property('content');
}).then(content => {
    console.log(content);
    _page.close();
    _ph.exit();
}).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Problem is the react content is not rendered, it only says: `<!-- react-empty: 1 -->"` where the actual react component should be loaded.

How can I scrap the rendered react component? I initially switched from a pure node-request solution to PhantomJS to fix this but now I am stuck.

---

UPDATE:

So I dont have a real solution yet. I switched to NightmareJS (https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) which has a nice `.wait('.some-selector')` function, which waits till the specified selector is loaded. This fixed my problems with dynamically loaded react components.

Comment: Does this package support receiving page.onError callbacks? Are there any errors?

Comment: Yes, thereis `console.log(status);` and it returns success. I get the whole HTML content except the react components where I get `<!-- react-empty: 1 -->`

Comment: I suspect `status` if from `page.open` callback and you need to check for errors in page.onError callback. Could be something like this: [Why I am not able to render my ReactJS application using PhantomJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38469005/why-i-am-not-able-to-render-my-reactjs-application-using-phantomjs-2-1-1)

Answer (score 3):

I think you should wait for rendering the react elements on the page after the page is loaded. An example of such a waiting-function, using Q promises, is below. This function returns a promise and checks for page state every 50ms. If the required page state is reached, the function resolves the promise. In the case of timeout, the function rejects the promise.

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
var Q = require('q');
var _ph, _page, _outObj;
var url = 'https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/';

phantom.create().then(ph => {
    _ph = ph;
    return _ph.createPage();
}).then(page => {
    _page = page;
    return _page.open(url);
}).then(status => {
    console.log(status);
    return waitState(textPopulated, 3);
}).then(() => {
    return _page.property('content');
}).then(content => {
    console.log(content);
_page.close();
_ph.exit();
}).catch(e => console.log(e));

function textPopulated() {
    return _page.evaluate(function() {
        var layer = document.querySelector('.ace_text-layer');
        return layer && layer.childElementCount;
    }).then(function(childElementCount) {
        console.log('childElementCount: ' + childElementCount);
        return childElementCount > 0;
    });
}

function waitState(state, timeout) {  // timeout in seconds is optional
    console.log('Start waiting for state: ' + state.name);

    var limitTime = timeout * 1000 || 20000;
    var startTime = new Date();

    return wait();

    function wait() {
        return state().then(function(result) {
            if (result) {
                console.log('Reached state: ' + state.name);
                return;
            } else if (new Date() - startTime > limitTime) {
                var errorMessage = 'Timeout state: ' + state.name;
                console.log(errorMessage);
                throw new Error(errorMessage);
            } else {
                return Q.delay(50).then(wait);
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            throw error;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, show how to use this with node.js bridge to PhantomJS that's mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Vaviloff I've adopted the example for the bridge

Comment: Sorry, I couldnt test your solution. I switched to NightmareJS (see my updated question). It greatly simplifies my problem.