# PhantomJS not loading dynamic content

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I've trying to load a page with PhantomJS and save it as a .png. However, the png that is created does not look like the original and is missing most of the body. Searching online, most of the similar problems were due to not waiting long enough to load the page. However, that hasn't resolved my issue. This is what I'm running:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var websiteAddress = 'http://poe.ninja/standard/currency';
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';
//viewportSize being the actual size of the headless browser
page.viewportSize = { width: 1920, height: 1080 };
//the clipRect is the portion of the page you are taking a screenshot of
page.clipRect = { top: 0, left: 0, width: 1920, height: 1080 };

page.open(websiteAddress, function (status) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        page.render('output.png');
        phantom.exit();
    }, 5000); // 5 sec should be enough
});
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in PhantomJS?

Here are images of what it should look like and what it actually looks like:

Expected: [image: Expected]
Actual: [image: Actual]

Comment: Add [page.onError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html) callback to check if there were any errors.

Answer (score 1):

The target site is a React application which probably uses some newer ES6 javascript syntax that is not available in current PhantomJS (as it uses an older QTWebkit rendering engine).

The solution is to use a polyfill library to make up for those missing methods as is done in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38471938/2715393

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `page.onResourceRequested = function(request) {}` and `page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {}` callbacks to keep a tally of started and completed resource downloads. Once your `onResourceReceived` callback detects that all downloads have finished, then call `page.render()`. This is more reliable than a 5 second timeout.

I do recommend waiting 0.5 seconds before `onResourceReceived` calls `page.render()` though, since it's possible for the last pending resource to finish but then trigger additional downloads.