# How to do screen capture of Angular2 application using phantomjs?

Tags: angular, phantomjs

Is there an example where phantomjs can do a screen capture of an angular2 application?

I am trying to work on this but is unable to get image i want.

Comment: by **unable to get image i want** what you mean? Do get any image? if so update the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I am not able to render my ReactJS application using PhantomJS 2.1.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38469005/why-i-am-not-able-to-render-my-reactjs-application-using-phantomjs-2-1-1)