# Parsing react app using phantom.js not loading whole page

Tags: reactjs, phantomjs

I have react app running fine. I want to use `phantom.js` for SEO. With the help of phantom.js, I want to store my page somewhere, and whenever a request comes from search bots, I want to serve them these saved pages.

The phantom.js code is:

```
var page;
var myurl="http://localhost:8080/login"; 

var renderPage = function (url) {
    page = require('webpage').create();
    page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1';


    page.onNavigationRequested = function(url, type, willNavigate, main) {
        if (main && url!=myurl) {
            myurl = url;
            console.log("redirect caught");
            page.close()
            renderPage(url);
        }
    };
page.open(url, function (status) {

    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(page.content);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 1000); // Change timeout as required to allow sufficient time 
    }
});

    // page.open(url, function(status) {
    //     console.log(status);
    //     if (status==="success") {
    //         console.log("success")
    //         console.log(page.content);
    //             // page.render('yourscreenshot.png');
    //             phantom.exit(0);
    //     } else {
    //         console.log("failed")
    //             phantom.exit(1);
    //     }
    // });
} 

renderPage(myurl);
```

Above code works fine, but with two constraints:

1. It works only on localhost, i.e., if `myurl="http://localhost:8080/login";` is changed to `myurl="http://192.168.x.x/login";`, it doesn't work.
2. If I am dynamically loading my component in react.js, above code doesn't work, even for localhost.

e.g., this works fine:

```
import Login from './containers/Login';
```

But, this doesn't:

```
const login = asyncComponent(() => import('./containers/login')
  .then(module => module.default), { name: 'login' });
```

Where asyncComponent() is:

```
import React from 'react';

export default (loader, collection) => (
  class AsyncComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.Component = null;
      this.state = { Component: AsyncComponent.Component };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      if (!this.state.Component) {
        loader().then((Component) => {
          AsyncComponent.Component = Component;

          this.setState({ Component });
        });
      }
    }

    render() {
      if (this.state.Component) {
        return (
          <this.state.Component { ...this.props } { ...collection } />
        )
      }

      return null;
    }
  }
);
```

I am looking for some help/guidance for:

1. How to manage SEO pages for reactjs? Is phantom.js a feasible solution?
2. How to manage redirects, i.e., for request on servers, I first redirect request to index.html and then render the page. I want to do the same in phantom.js, get the page after redirection, which is not working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Previous versions of PhantomJS wouldn't support ES6, see a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38471938/2715393

Or you could download and use a newer 2.5 beta version with modern Webkit engine that should open ReactJS sites fine from here: https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads