# Phantomjs "Module X not available!" when trying to render a AngularJS webpage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, phantomjs

I spent a couple hours trying to find an issue that gave me any clues to solve my issues, but couldn't find anything relevant.

I am working on some SEO for a website (I'm no SEO specialist, am currently taking some courses and reading lots of articles on it), and one thing that I found out was the "Fetch and Render" as Google on Google Search Console.

However the website, which has loads of AngularJS (1.5.x) components, was just rendered the header, which I implied meant that the js didn't load properly and the Angular components couldn't been initialized.

Since, I then found out (can't confirm) that Google Search Console used PhantomJS to render the pages, so I decided to give it a try on my local environment.

We use Webpack to bundle all js files together, and it works as expected both on local and production environments, however it appears that PhantomJS has some problems when trying to render the bundled files.

Every module a page tries to bootstrap throws an error when running PhantomJS:

> [$injector:nomod] Module '(moduleName)' is not available! You either
>   misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a
>   module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
>   argument.

But as I said, all browsers correctly loads all modules, apparently there is no error on the modules declaration, all imports are in order, everything should work as expected. Except it doesn't.

If you think an excerpt of the script could bring some light to the matter, I'll include when required, as the code is a bit sensitive, there is a lot of it (couldn't think about a bit that could be helpful), and since it works correctly almost everywhere it doesn't seem to me to be the issue, but I could definitely be wrong.

I'm sorry, I hate to post questions without code, but I'm a bit overwhelmed by this one.

Has anyone faced a similar issue?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Kind regards.

Comment: This is probably due to PhantomJS' lack of ES6 support. Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38471938/2715393) or even better migrate to [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/)